# Established way to convert NSURL.scheme to SecProtocolType?

Tags: swift, enumeration, nsurl

I my Mac Swift application, I need to use a C API that requires a SecProtocolType value. I have a valid NSURL, with a scheme string, for example "http" or "ftp". I can do string searching with the raw values in SecProtocolType, but that looks like an invitation for "unexpected behavior" :)
Is there a better or standard way?
TY!

Comment: I seems I have misunderstood the nature of objective-c `enum`s as used in Swift. An actual Swift `Enumeration` could have the features I expected, but `SecProtocolType` is not a “real” `Enumeration` object or data structure, ‘it’ is merely a placeholder  for some integer values. `FourCharCodes` are not iterable, searchable or checkable, they are just integers created from four `char` values.  So anything goes when creating one. Boo Hiss.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote above, one does not convert a URL scheme to a `SecProtocolType` `FourCharCode`. One can CREATE a `FourCharCode` from the first four letters of a scheme. But note that many schemes are not protocols ( i.e email:, file:// etc.) and that the `SecProtocolType` codes are arbitrary abbreviations (i.e the code for "https" is `htps` etc.). Here is a crude Swift function that creates a `FourCharCode` from a truncated or padded String. Sometimes, this result is the same as the Apple `SecProtocolType` :/

```html
import Security

func scheme2Protocol(schemeString: String) -> SecProtocolType
{
    var rawResult = kSecProtocolTypeAny
    var searchString = ""
    var n:Int = 0
    if(count(schemeString) == 4)
    {
        searchString = schemeString.lowercaseString
    }
    else
    {
        if(count(schemeString) < 4)
        {
            searchString = schemeString.lowercaseString
            let amountToPad = 4 - count(schemeString)
            for _ in 1...amountToPad
            {
                searchString = searchString + " "
            }
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = schemeString.substringFromIndex(advance(schemeString.startIndex,4)).lowercaseString
        }
    }
    
    for UniCodeChar in searchString.unicodeScalars
    {
        n = (n << 8) + (Int(UniCodeChar.value) & 255)
    }
    
    let typedResult:SecProtocolType = SecProtocolType(n)//**Boo Hiss. This C enum is not type-safe at all.**//
    
    return typedResult
}
```